# Mi aplicación Xamarin Forms reinicia dispositivos Android como Samsung J5 o Sony Xperia Z5 cuando inicia

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, prism

Desarrollé una aplicación con Xamarin Forms y Prism Form. Cuando instalo la apk en algunos dispositivos Android causa que el dispositivo se reinicie con solo iniciar la aplicación. Sin embargo, esto solo me pasa en algunos teléfonos como un Samsung J5 y un Sony Xperia Z5, curiosamente ambos con la versión 7.1 de Android. En mi teléfono Xiaomi con Android versión 10 funciona bien. ¿Estaré configurando el despliegue de la apk de forma incorrecta o algo en el manifiesto de Android?

Comment: Hi there Gustavo, you are at [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor agrega detalles de que realiza tu app, que APIs usa, como esta configurada en build.gradle y Manifest, revisaste el LogCat?. Te sugerimos revisar [ask] para que conozcas como formular preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos.

Comment: ¿En el manifiesto que version minima tienes y de destino? ¿Has probado a debuguear en algun emulador con 7.1? Generalmente ese problema es debido a que no soporta alguna caracteristica esa version.

Comment: Tengo en versión mínima Android 5.0 y versión de destino Android 9.0. No he probado en emulador con 7.1, lo probaré, gracias!!.

Comment: Agrega la configuración a tu pregunta y lo que se muestra en el LogCat por favor.